# Pygame duplicating graphics

Tags: python, pygame

When moving 'player1' all previous locations are still show on the screen leaving a trail. How can i get the screen to only apply the image at the current location.

I'm using windows 10 and python 2.7, I've looked other peoples code and can't find anything different to do with the player graphics.

whats supposed to happen is a player should be able to move without blotting out the map with them self.

```
PLAYER = pygame.image.load('player1.png')
player_position = [16,0]

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            # right arrow key
            if (event.key == K_RIGHT) and (player_position[0] < MAPWIDTH - 1):
                # player move right
                player_position[0] +=1
            # left arrow key
            elif (event.key == K_LEFT) and (player_position[0] > 0):
                # player move left
                player_position[0] -=1
            # up arrow key
            elif (event.key == K_UP) and (player_position[1] > 0):
                # player move up
                player_position[1] -=1
            # down arrow key
            elif (event.key == K_DOWN) and (player_position[1] < MAPHEIGHT - 1):
                # player move down
                player_position[1] +=1
    #load the player graphics
    view.blit(PLAYER, (player_position[0]*TILESIZE, 
    player_position[1]*TILESIZE))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: use this in loop: `view.fill((0,0,0))`

Answer (score 0):

**Replace it with this:**

```
PLAYER = pygame.image.load('player1.png')
player_position = [16,0]

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            # right arrow key
            if (event.key == K_RIGHT) and (player_position[0] < MAPWIDTH - 1):
                # player move right
                player_position[0] +=1
            # left arrow key
            elif (event.key == K_LEFT) and (player_position[0] > 0):
                # player move left
                player_position[0] -=1
            # up arrow key
            elif (event.key == K_UP) and (player_position[1] > 0):
                # player move up
                player_position[1] -=1
            # down arrow key
            elif (event.key == K_DOWN) and (player_position[1] < MAPHEIGHT - 1):
                # player move down
                player_position[1] +=1

    view.fill((0,0,0))
    #load the player graphics
    view.blit(PLAYER, (player_position[0]*TILESIZE, 
    player_position[1]*TILESIZE))
    pygame.display.update()
```

**Added:** `view.fill((0,0,0))`